# how to debug TC pivotal server

Tags: spring, tomcat, tcserver

I have a SPRING WEB project which I imported from nearly the same environnement and it was working perfectly. When I imported it to the current PC it didn't work.

this is what the pivotal server says :

```
févr. 28, 2017 10:56:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFOS: Initialization processed in 8010 ms
févr. 28, 2017 10:56:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFOS: Server startup in 2389 ms
```

there's no log other than that.

this is the catalina log [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxIjuBy2ah16OWR6SUJ1X2lpZDQ)

and when I start the server I get this page :  `The requested resource is not available.`

How can I debug this ?

Or how do I activate the debugging of the server ?

Any help will be appreciated.Thank you.

**What steps I need to do to identify the problem ?**

Comment: I found a lovely bug like this a while back. Don't go too far down the rabbit hole. If I recall, I spent several hours on it, and it was just a syntax error in one of the XML files. I think it was web.xml or my servlet.xml

Comment: Yep you're right plus I had to use `classic-logback` and put it in `WEB-INF/classes/` which is wierd cause the project was running perfectly before.